# Windows phone 7 FileNotFoundException System.Windows.debug.resources

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, filenotfoundexception

I get the following exception when navigating to a page in my windows phone 7.1 silverlight application. What does this mean, and how can I solve this?

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
Message=File or assembly name 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', or one of its dependencies, was not found.
StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.throwVersion37CompatException(ExceptionType newEType, String newString, ExceptionType oldEType, String oldString)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Windows.Resx..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Resx.GetLoader()
   at System.Windows.Resx.GetStringHelper(String name)
   at System.Windows.Resx.GetString(String name)
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToPropertyInSource(Boolean isSourceCollectionViewCurrentItem)
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToProperty()
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ReConnect(Object newSource)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReConnect(Object source)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(Object sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnTreeParentUpdated(DependencyObject newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateTreeParent(IManagedPeer oldParent, IManagedPeer newParent, Boolean bIsNewParentAlive, Boolean keepReferenceToParent)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(IntPtr oldParentElement, IntPtr parentElement, IntPtr childElement, Byte bIsParentAlive, Byte bKeepReferenceToParent, Byte bCanCreateParent)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Measure_WithDesiredSizeNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure_WithDesiredSize(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure_WithDesiredSize(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this crashing exception, too, and in my case it always happened when I had a wrong binding in my xaml.

For example I've got the property:

```
public String Name {get;set;}
```

And in xaml I mistyped the binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Namme}"/>
```

In my case this caused the FileNotFound-Exception for System.Windows.debug.resources.

When I fixed the binding everything worked again.

Answer (score 3):

its a bug on wp 7.1 check that msdn [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/2B040008-A240-470D-91AF-E998984FFF12)