# How do I override ClientHttpwebRequest.Failed()?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone application that I run inside 7.1 Emulator. I have this code:

```
 WebRequest resuest = ///
 using (HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 {
```

and once control gets into `GetResponse()` I first have `FileNotFound` first-chance exception

> File or assembly name 'System.Windows.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

with the following call stack

```
mscorlib.dll!System.ThrowHelper.throwVersion37CompatException(System.ExceptionType newEType, string newString, System.ExceptionType oldEType, string oldString) + 0x19 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(string assemblyString) + 0x5d bytes    
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Resx.Resx() + 0x29 bytes  
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Resx.GetLoader() + 0x1f bytes 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Resx.GetString(string name, out bool fallbackUsed, object[] args) 
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Resx.GetString(string name, object[] args)    
System.Windows.dll!System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.Failed(object sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0xf8 bytes   
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.InternalWebRequest.OnDownloadFailed(object sender, MS.Internal.ErrorEventArgs args) + 0x15 bytes 
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(int typeIndex, System.Delegate handlerDelegate, object sender, object args) + 0x3f4 bytes   
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName) + 0x178 bytes 
[External Code]
```

and when I click "Continue" I get unhandled `WebException`

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

The first thing looks like a variation of [a well-known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9693211/57428). Now because of this problem my program just wouldn't work. I've read that this may somehow be connected to Fiddler so I tried both with and without Fiddler but the behavior is the same all times. When Fiddler is running I don't see the request leaving my machine although the URL the request is to be sent is a URL of a server on the external network.

The call stack shows that there was some problem that resulted in `ClientHttpWebRequest.Failed()` called and then the latter failed to work. So maybe I could override it and somehow bypass the problematic code with `Resx.GetString()`?

Can I override `ClientHttpWebRequest.Failed()` or otherwise have problematic code bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the initial question, but I seem to have worked the problem around.

The deal is I'm behind corporate Forefront TMG and I have Forefront TMG Client running on my computer so that all programs can have their requests passed to the Internet. The TMG server is called say `tmgserver`.

So I open "Internet Options" (accessible from Internet Explorer) and on the "Connections" tab there's "LAN Settings" button and when I click it I see that there's a checkbox "Use proxy server for your LAN" and the server name is `tmgserver` and port number is 8080. Now I just clear the checkbox and click "Apply" the necessary number of times and the problem is resolved.